# What purpose did Guruji have with Ganesh Gaitonde 20 years in advance?

Tags: plot-explanation, sacred-games

In the Netflix web series Sacred Games, it is revealed by Jojo that for the last 20 years, they were making a fool out of Gaitonde. Everytime he believed he was immortal, he was being saved by Guriji's group. Every aspect of his life for 20 years was scripted by Guruji and his group.

The question has to be asked. What purpose did fooling Gaitonde serve? Why was he so important and integral to the plan? That they had to choose him 20 years in advance?

If only a sacrifice is to be needed, why not Bhosle? He was a member of the group too.

I do not understand the motivation or importance of this plot element